# React Router returns a blank page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have it rendering in Index.JS the first one. But it returns a blank page with no error, I don't know what I'm doing wrong?

I have small pages for stuff and contact to just for the content when navigating.

```
  import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import App from './App';
    import './index.css';
    import Home from './home';
    import Stuff from './stuff';
    import Contact from './contact';


    var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
    var Route = ReactRouter.Route;
    var Routes = ReactRouter.Routes;
    var IndexRoute = ReactRouter.IndexRoute;




    ReactDOM.render(
      <Routes>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
      <Route path="stuff" component={Stuff} />
      <Route path="contact" component={Contact} />
      </Route>
      </Routes>,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );



import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Alert from 'react-s-alert';
import 'react-s-alert/dist/s-alert-default.css';
import 'react-s-alert/dist/s-alert-css-effects/bouncyflip.css';
import Modal from 'react-awesome-modal';
import Examples from './modal';
import Home from './home';
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var Link = ReactRouter.Link;

    class App extends Component {



      render() {
        return (

          <div className="App">
            <div className="App-header">
              <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />

              <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
              <ul className="nav">
              <li><Link to = "/">Home</Link></li>
               <li><Link to = "/stuff">Stuff</Link></li>
               <li><Link to = "/contact">Contact</Link></li>
              </ul>

              <div className="content">
              {this.props.children}
              </div>
            </div>

    export default App;
```

Comment: You may want to consider pasting your code better... for example giving different files different names and so forth. It makes it easier for one to try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wrap your routes with `<Router></Router>` component, not `<Routes />`:

```
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

ReactDOM.render(
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
          <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
           <Route path="stuff" component={Stuff} />
          <Route path="contact" component={Contact} />
        </Route>
      </Router>,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
```